# SceneKit: scaling SCNNode doesn't change size by expected amount

Tags: transform, scenekit, scnnode, scnscene

This [attached DAE model](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/h6itbar1leetmko/AAApCMdnkUJj4YTvyFST3MuQa?dl=0&preview=Tiki.dae) has a height of ~324 units as shown by its bounding box.

In a SceneKit, however, if you set the Y-scale to 0.01, the height doesn't become ~3.24. It becomes smaller than 3, which you can prove by fitting it comfortably within a sphere of height 3 (radius of 1.5).

If your asset is too large for a SCNScene, how can you precisely scale its size?

Answer (score 2):

your model is smaller than 324

the bounding boxes of the leafs are rotated with the leafs making your overall bounding box bigger than your geometry - turn on Display Bounding Boxes and you'll see. i suggest freezing transformations in your modeling software, or just be aware that your model is not 324